# Python3 urllib POST with HTTPS

Tags: python, post, https, urllib, python-3.3

I just started working with urllib in python 3.3.3 and I can use `urllib.request.urlopen()` for making POST requests. However, what I would like to do is a POST with HTTPS. I saw that the documentation of `urlopen` says "Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use data" (and I need the 'data' parameter for the POST request).

Then I saw that `urllib.request.HTTPSHandler` seems to be able to make a HTTPS POST via its `https_open()`. Unfortunately, it seems I can't figure out how to use this function. For now I just want to do a simple HTTPS GET with this handler, so what I tried to do is

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.Request("https://www.google.com")
handler = urllib.request.HTTPSHandler()
handler.https_open(r)
```

but this leads to `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

How can I get `HTTPSHandler.https_open()` to work? Or does `urlopen` call the `https_open` function if I used

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPSHandler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

before and actually does make a HTTPS POST request already? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `data=None` with `urlopen`.

Or use [Requests](http://python-requests.org)

Comment: Hi, as I said in the post I need the "data" parameter because I have to do a POST request. Without data, I can only make GET requests.